# Deshabilitar boton

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, jsf

Quiero que al hacer clic en un `h:commandButton` que esta dentro de un modal de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) deshabilite un botón que esta dentro de un panel.

He tratado de hacerlo con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) pero no me sirve, solo sirve si el `CommandButton` esta fuera del modal.

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar.

```
<div class="panel greenPanel">
    <div id="tituloPedidos" class="panel-heading panelGreen">
        <div id="tituloPedidos" class="panel-title">Aguacate</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="../RecursosModulos/images/productos/aguacate.jpg"></img>
        <div id="textoPedidos">
            Precio por kilogramo: $5.000
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer **<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block contact" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registro" style="font-size: 16px">
        <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span> Añadir al carrito</button>**
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="registro" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" role="dialog" style="width: 750px;margin-left: 400px;margin-top: 10px;">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                            <div id="icono"  style="font-size: 60px; text-align: center">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                <legend>Añadir producto</legend>
                            </div>

                            <h:form id="formularioSolicitudPedido" class="form-horizontal" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">

                                <!-- Seleccionar producto -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nombreProducto">Producto</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <select id="nombreProducto" name="nombreProducto" class="form-control" required="true" onchange="valores()">
                                            <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="1">--Seleccione un producto--</option>
                                            <c:forEach var="objProducto" items="#{controladorProducto.listarProductos()}">
                                                <option value="#{objProducto.codigoProducto}" selected="#{controladorPedido.codigoProducto==objProducto.codigoProducto ? true:''}" >#{objProducto.nombreProducto}</option>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </select>

                                        <label id='precioU' class="col-md-12 control-label"  for="precioUnitario" style="float: right; font-size: 15px;">Precio por kilogramo: &nbsp; <span>#{controladorPedido.precio}</span> </label>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Seleccionar cantidad-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cantidadProducto">Cantidad</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <input type="number" id="cantidadProducto" name="cantidadProducto"  min="0" max="1000" placeholder="Kilogramos" class="form-control input-md" onchange="Calcular(this)" value="0" required="true"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Clasificacion producto -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div id="ayuda" class="center col-md-1" style="font-size:1.5em; margin-right: 116px; margin-top:5px"><div class="tip" data-tip="Baja: Solo pulpa. Alta: Fruta "><i class=" fa fa-question-circle"></i></div></div>
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="clasificacionProducto">Clasificación</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5" required="true"> 
                                        <select id="clasificacionProducto" name="clasificacionProducto" class="form-control" required="true" title="Select one of these options">
                                            <option selected="true" disabled="true">--Seleccione una clasificación--</option>
                                            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                                            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <!-- Precio -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="precioPedido">Precio Total</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-5"> 
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="precioPedido"> Precio (in COP)</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon fa fa-usd"></div>
                                            <input type="text" id="precioPedido" name="precioPedido" class="form-control"  placeholder="Precio Total" readonly="true" value="0"></input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Cedula -->
                                <div class="form-group hidden">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cedulaCliente">Cedula</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <input type="text" id="cedulaCliente" name="cedulaCliente" class="form-control input-md" readonly="true" value="#{controladorUsuario.objUsuarioLogin.idUsuario}"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Boton -->
                                <div id="boton">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="boton"></label>
                                        **<h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  value="Añadir" style="float: right; margin-right: 190px;"></h:commandButton>**
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </h:form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- FIN MODAL AGREGAR PRODUCTO A CARRITO-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Solución con jQuery y asumiendo que solo hay un elemento con `id="boton"`:

```
$('#boton .btn').click(function (e) {
    // Si deseas seguir haciendo el submit, ignora la siguiente línea
    e.preventDefault();

   $('.greenPanel button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```